# Application state changes right after action is dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to change the state using setState and then call an action with new state but React dispatch the action right before the new state has been set. how do I wait for the new state and then dispatch the action ?

```
addressInput = e => {
  this.setState({
    address: e.target.value
  });
  this.props.filterSearch(this.state.address) //this will be called before state is set                              
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.setState` provides a callback as a second parameter which is called after the state change has occurred. You should use the callback as follows

```
addressInput = e => {
  this.setState({
    address: e.target.value
  },
  this.props.filterSearch(this.state.address));
}
```

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.